# Why is saveField() not saving the record in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6, cakephp-2.x

I am using cakephp 2.6.7.

In Model/ResellerAccount:

```
<?php

class ResellerAccount extends AppModel {

    var $name = "resellerAccounts";           
}

?>
```

My table name is reseller_accounts.

in controller:

```
function moneySentToreseller($id = null) {
    if ($id) {
        $this->loadModel('ResellerAccount');

        $this->ResellerAccount->id = $id;
        $this->ResellerAccount->saveField("ResellerAccount.status", "sent");
        $msg = '
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong> Money send to this reseller succeesfully </strong>
           </div>';
        $this->Session->setFlash($msg);
    }
    return $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

But the field is not being updated. Whats wrong is going on in my code?

Comment: I noticed you ask a lot of questions on cake, you should really take some time and read the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#getting-started).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html):

> When using this method, $fieldName should only contain the name of the field, not the name of the model and field.

Try saving as follows:

```
    $this->ResellerAccount->saveField("status", "sent");
```

Careful also with the name of your model:

```
    var $name = "resellerAccounts";
```

should be

```
    public $name = "ResellerAccount";
```

Comment: Side note: I highly recommend NOT using saveField anymore, at all. It is a function that is discontinued in 3.x, as such it would be smarter to stick to save() for better upgrade compatibility. See https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-upgrade/wiki/Tips-Upgrading-to-CakePHP-2.x-3.x#modelsavefield

Comment: Good to know! Thanks!